# Typescript - assign null to variable

Tags: typescript, types, null, nullable

I have a class like this:

```
export class Signal {
    method: (d: any) => void;
    otherMethod: (d: any) => void;


    public resetMethods(): void {
        this.method = null;
        this.otherMethod = null;
    }
}
```

unfortunately this will not compile anymore, until some previous version didn't give problems, now in the compilation phase I get the following error:

```
 Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(d: any) => void'.
```

for the structure of my code it is important to make those properties "null" and reassign them later, how can I remedy the compiler's complaints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null
export class Signal {
    method: Nullable<(d: any) => void> = null;

    public resetMethods(): void {
        this.method = null;
    }
}
```

Create custom type `Nullable`, very useful

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQQwEYIgHgCoD4oC8U2UAPlAHaIIBQEAHmAPYBOwUAxigM7dQDKASwDmFZAigBvGlFlQAthGAALJgBMAXLGpoMmABSaoyCiACUhfADcmgtfiJUkAbhoy5YOOkEcoLCNxKALJKqmrc+mZaNnZS7nJyKoLcAHSKKuqElNSuCQC+NHlAA)

Comment: The other answers were also doable but i loved this one!! TNX

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is more general, nice one.

Answer (score 2):

As the code is right now, you have to declare the fields as optional anyway, since they are not assigned a value. And it that case you could assign `undefined` to make TS happy:

```
export class Signal {
    method?: (d: any) => void;
    //    ^
    otherMethod?: (d: any) => void;
    //         ^


    public resetMethods(): void {
        this.method = undefined;
        this.otherMethod = undefined;
    }
}
```

If you really want/need to assign `null`, then you can use a union type:

```
export class Signal {
    method?: ((d: any) => void) | null;
    otherMethod?: ((d: any) => void) | null;


    public resetMethods(): void {
        this.method = null;
        this.otherMethod = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: mmmmmm  `(d: any) => void) | null;` 
so it wouldn't be like saying that the return type of the method is void or null ??

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Without `?` typescript still complains because the fields don't have an initial value. If they do get a value in the constructor but it's left out in this example, then it's not needed.

Comment: @Plastic: No, because of the parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming the constructor definitely assigns it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Define a type for your "methods":

```
type MyMethod = (d: any) => void;
```

Then either declare them with that `| null`:

```
method: MyMethod | null;
```

Or give yourself a convenience type:

```
type NullableMyMethod = MyMethod | null;
```

and use that

```
method: NullableMyMethod;
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiMWACwPYBMoF4oAo0C4oBDAOxAEosA+KANxQEs0BuAWACgPRIoA5AVwA2gogCNBEOAmTosseIlQYAPlBJDBbTuwDGIgM76oAZQYBzEkUFQA3hygOoAW0XpCA4WIlTXGbOuEtRygUZAgAJ2kldw0vSQUZPzUNLXtHMH5xBh0ocIh9RCj0fRxyQnomWzTgh2QGfQA6F0S5AM1qmrrG0KQIoqS2oMcAXw5hoA)

Comment: method: MyMethod | null; was the cleanest way for me.   Got to keep it simple.